# How to avoid revealing to (soon to be ex) colleagues the name of the new employer?

Tags: colleagues, job-change

I'm about to move to my new job, and my current colleagues are curious about the new enterprise that hired me. I discussed with them the organization, benefits, pros and cons of the actual vs the new position, but they insist on knowing the exact name of the enterprise.

Not sure why exactly, but as more as they are becoming pushy, the more I don't wan't to disclose it (maybe it's because we never really bonded that much).

Could you suggest a way to gently stop this kind of questions?

Few notes:

- for the moment, I'm stalling saying that I'll reveal the name later.
- I'm comfortable with the position I'm going to cover in the new
  enterprise.
- as a last resort, I could always lie and provide an incorrect name (I'd like a bit less drastic solution, if possible).

Edit:

I'm more interested how to handle the issue with my colleagues, not with my boss (as discussed [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21232/how-can-i-avoid-telling-my-boss-about-the-new-company-that-ill-be-working-for-d)), while [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/under-what-circumstances-is-it-ok-to-tell-your-colleagues-where-you-will-be-goin) answer is closer to my question, although it addresses the opposite issue (when it's ok to tell / how not to tell).

I would have prefer to wait until the last day but I had to give advance notice of few month before leaving in order to allow my current employer to look for a suitable replacement (otherwise my employer can withold my last paychecks). At that point my colleagues (at least some of them) are involved in the process of selecting a replacement and my resignation is not confidential any more.

p.s. Still don't have the permission to write comments, only to edit my original question

Comment: What’s wrong with “I’d rather not say?”

Comment: Also related: [Under what circumstances is it OK to tell your colleagues where you will be going after a resignation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/under-what-circumstances-is-it-ok-to-tell-your-colleagues-where-you-will-be-goin)

Comment: @ThinkTank About your edit, why do you have to share with them *"organization, benefits, pros and cons of the actual vs the new position"* while giving notice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Direct communication is best. Repeat as often as necessary.

> I don't want to disclose this now. Please don't ask me.

Dodging the question by making awkward excuses will only make them more curious.

For future reference, if you are not comfortable talking about the new job with coworkers, don't tell them about it at all until you are maybe a couple of days away from leaving.

Comment: *"until you are maybe a couple of days away from leaving."* - I would just say it on the day of if you manager has not already informed everyone. If your manager does not disclose it, I would not neither.

Comment: I feel the problem is not so much that the OP mentioned they're leaving but that they discussed the pros and cons in detail. No wonder their coworkers are curious.

Comment: @Llewellyn Yes, I had started writing about that in my answer, but thought it would sound too much like lecturing the OP, so chose to skip it. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't wish to tell your current colleagues where you're going, you don't have to. You can feel free to say: "I don't feel comfortable disclosing it," "I would rather not say," or whatever your reasons are.

Something to think about: networking is valuable, and if you're on linked in or other social media, it's likely that where you are going to work is fairly public information. Deciding to not tell people in person and publishing it on LinkedIn may make you look a little bit weird, but it's still something you can decide to do, and if you just tell people that you'd rather not discuss it then they should understand.

However, if you continually tell people you'll tell them later then they will probably keep asking.

Answer (score -1):

"I can't tell you the name of my new company, as it wouldn't be fair to {current employer}, and might get me into trouble with {current employer} when you all resign to come and join me."